# DNS server unreachable from one client

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router, dns, windows-server

I have a home network with 3 computers: a server running Windows Server 2016, DNS, AD, DHCP, IIS, etc, a laptop running Windows 10 and connected to the router over WiFi, and a desktop, also running windows 10, connected to the router via hardwired Ethernet cable.

I run all of them pretty much 24/7.  This morning when I got up, the laptop is getting a failed DNS resolution on any domain I try. Trying nslookup from the command prompt, I'm getting "DNS request timeout".  That is true even if I explicitly specify the IP for DNS server (e.g., "nslookup google.com 192.168.1.97"), using either my local server's IP, the IP of the ISP's DNS, or the IP of resolver1.opendns.com.

But everything is functioning normally  on both the server and on the desktop.  I can ping the server from the laptop with no problems, so it's not a connectivity issue.  I can also ping the outside world via IP address from the laptop, just not via domain name.

My iPhone, which goes through the same WiFi and router (not sure if it goes through the same DNS server or not - it might be going through the ISP's DNS server) can access arbitrary sites by name.

I have tried rebooting both the laptop and the server, to no avail. I tried `ipconfig /flushdns` on the laptop, with no change.

One other clue, but I don't know what it means. When I hover the mouse over the WiFi icon in the Systray, it usually says "hq.infotouchsys.com Internet access". When I first started troubleshooting this, it was saying "hq.infotouchsys.com 2 (Unauthenticated) Internet access".  Now, after changing connections a few times, it's saying "NETGEAR90-5G Internet access", i.e, the WiFI SSID rather than my domain name.

I am completely baffled as to 1) Why this started suddenly with no known triggering event and 2) Why it's only occurring on the laptop.

Comment: Try temporarily disabling your firewall to see if that helps. Something may be blocking DNS.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't do anything.

Comment: Please run `nslookup -d2 <dns_server_ip> google.com` and [edit] your question with the result.

Comment: Having done nothing more than turn dns server debug logs on, things now appear to be working.  I still don't understand why it stopped working, or why it started working, but I guess I will let it alone.  Thanks, everyone, for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

First things first.  Run the following command:

```
 ipconfig /flushdns
```

And restest.  If that doesn't work, do an

```
 ipconfig /all
```

and check to make sure that the dns listed matches your settings.  I've seen viruses that mess with DNS.  I recommend running an MBAM scan too.

Try to set your laptop dns configuration to 8.8.8.8 and test.  That will let you know if it's having a hard time communicating to your dns server.  You can also flush dns on your workstation to see if it starts having the same issues as your laptop as dns is cached.

If that doesn't work, check your host file

[How to Edit Your Hosts File on Windows, Mac, or Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

NS requests go to the host file before they go to external DNS servers.

If that doesn't work, dig into your event logs.

Comment: thanks, Patrick. As I said in the original post, I have already done an ipconfig /flushdns, and it didn't help.  I have verified the dns settings in ipconfig /all. And I have done a MalwareBytes scan.

Comment: My last response got cut short.When I set the dns address of TCP/IP properties to 8.8.8.8 as you suggested, things started working. I'm not familiar with what that does, so I don't know how to interpret it. Also, examination of the EventViewer showed an error from the group policy servers saying it was unable to communicate with the Domain Server. No clue as to why, since it can ping it and access the shared files on it.

Comment: If 8.8.8.8 (google public DNS) works then the issue is with your dns server, not the laptop.  The reason your workstation is still working is because it's dns is cached.

Don't check general logs, take a look at dns specific logging.  A couple of links to help you out:


https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13640.windows-server-dns-read-the-dns-debug-log.aspx

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn800669(v=ws.11)